# Как поменять определенные элементы массива местами?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2

Есть массив обьктов :

```
arr=[
{
order:1,
name:name,
},
{
order:1,
name:name1,
},
{
order:2,
name:name2,
},{
order:4,
name:name3,
},
{
order:7,
name:name4,
},
order:7,
name:name5,
},
order:8,
name:name6,
},
order:8,
name:name7,
},
order:8,
name:name8,
},
order:9,
name:name9,
},
.......
order:100,
name:name100,
}]
```

Он выводится в таблицу:

| order | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 1 | name2 |
| 2 | name3 |
| 4 | name4 |
| 7 | name5 |
| 7 | name6 |
| 8 | name7 |
| 8 | name8 |
| 8 | name9 |
| 9 | name10 |

При клике на строку  выделяются элементы, причем элементы с один order выделяются как один обьект.
Есть две кнопки: стрелка вниз и вверх, для перемещения соответственно.
Если  обьект состоит из одного элемента перемещаешь с другим который тоже из одного жлемента состоит понятно все.

А как можно поменять местами если выделенная строка состоит из несколько элементов, жмешь вверху то есть, выбранный должен поменяться местами с вышестоящим и поменять поле order у этих обьектов местами.

То есть жмем на 7 строку(index=6).выделяется сразу три строки - 7,8,9. Жмем на кнопку стрелка вверх. Он должен поменяться местами с предыдущим обьектом, то есть строками 5 и 6.
то есть на строке с индексом 4, 5,6 должны стоять  name7,name8,name9 и у них у всех в поле order Должны быть 7. А на строках с индексами 7,8 name 5,6 соответственно  и в полях  в поле order стоять 8.

| order | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 1 | name2 |
| 2 | name3 |
| 4 | name4 |
| 8 | name7 |
| 8 | name8 |
| 8 | name9 |
| 7 | name5 |
| 7 | name6 |
| 9 | name10 |

Я попробовала вот так

this.mySelectionIndex - массив с  индексами выбранных строк.
count - число строк обьекта с  которым надо поменяться
ordClickUp -this.arr[this.mySelectionIndex[0] - 1].order

получается  в данной ситуации:

```
this.mySelectionIndex = [4,5,6];
count=2;
 for (let k = 0; k < this.mySelectionIndex.length- 1; k++) {
      this.arr[this.mySelectionIndex[k]-count] );
        [
          this.arr[this.mySelectionIndex[k]],
          this.arr[this.mySelectionIndex[k]-count ]
        ] = [
          this.arr[this.mySelectionIndex[k]-count],
          this.arr[this.mySelectionIndex[k]]
        ];
       this.arr[this.mySelectionIndex[0] + k].order = ordClickUp;
        count--;
        }
```

но результат не тот. в чем ошибка?
Получается пока так:

| order | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 1 | name2 |
| 2 | name3 |
| 4 | name4 |
| 8 | name7 |
| 7 | name5 |
| 8 | name8 |
| 7 | name6 |
| 8 | name9 |
| 9 | name10 |

Answer (score 1):

Смена местами двух значений, без создания временной переменной (потому что с переменной - слишком очевидно и скучно):

```js
const arr = [
  { order: 1, name: 'foo' },  // [0]
  { order: 2, name: 'bar' },
  { order: 3, name: 'baz' },  // [2]
];
// для наглядности, здесь я присвою индексы перемещаемых элементов переменным (это не обязательно, конечно же)
let [idxA, idxB] = [0, 2];

// меняем местами элементы массива
arr.splice(idxB, 0, ...arr.splice(idxA, 1, ...arr.splice(idxB, 1)));

// опционально: меняем местами числа в свойстве order (через побитовую операцию XOR)
[idxA, idxB, idxA].forEach(idx => arr[idx].order = arr[idxA].order ^ arr[idxB].order);

console.log(arr);
```

Вложенное подвыражение `arr.splice(idxA, 1, ...arr.splice(idxB, 1))` выполняет перенос элемента с индексом `idxB` на место элемента с индексом `idxA`, вернув удаленный элемент (с индексом `idxA`) обернутый в массив. Затем, этот удаленный элемент добавляется на место перенесенного элемента (то есть, на индекс `idxB`) внешним подвыражением `arr.splice(idxB, 0, ...<результатВложенногоSplice>)`.

**Нюанс:** это несколько раз мутирует массив с изменением его длины, т.е. может быть не очень быстрым способом (я не проверял его производительность).

*// О методе массива `splice` можно прочесть [на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).*

---

Смена местами чисел в свойстве `order` объектов выполняется последовательным выполнением [исключающего ИЛИ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%C2%AB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%C2%BB). То есть, это по сути

```
orderA = orderA ^ orderB;
orderB = orderA ^ orderB;
orderA = orderA ^ orderB;
```

**Нюанс:** этим способом безопасно менять местами только целые числа со значением по модулю <2млрд., примерно (т.к. побитовые операторы в JS приводят значение своих операндов к 32-битным целым числам).